# tar files excluding those with given pattern

Tags: tar

I have the following directory structure (all names given here are directories; they all contain files and subdirectories):

```
a
a/a, a/b, a/c, ..., a/x, a/y, a/z
a/a/a, a/a/b, a/a/c, ..., a/a/x, a/a/y, a/a/z
a/b/a, a/b/b, a/b/c, ..., a/b/x, a/b/y, a/b/z
...
a/x/a, a/x/b, a/x/c, ..., a/x/x, a/x/y, a/x/z
```

The letters are just descriptive; they're not the real names. Also, the depth is variable, with a maximum of around 10 subdirectories.

I would like to tar the whole tree from directory `a` but exclude anything named `x`. So, in the above, I would like to tar everything except `a/x` and everything under it; `a/a/x` and everything under it; and `a/b/x` and everything under it.

I was thinking of using `find` and `grep -v` but I'm wondering, is there an easier way?

Comment: Are you using GNU `tar`, which has `--exclude`?

Comment: @Kusalananda yes, GNU tar. Now I see that `--exclude` is exactly what I need! Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for @Kusalananda for the comment, I can use the `--exclude` option available in GNU tar:

To exclude everything under any directory named `x` (but not the directory itself):

```
tar cf a.tar --exclude='x/*' a
```

To exclude directory `x` and everything under it (but note that this also excludes any regular files named `x` too):

```
tar cf a.tar --exclude='x' a
```